# Pegar dado do banco e comparar CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Boa tarde galera,

Estava eu tentando criar um sistema de login para um trabalho da faculdade quando me deparei com o seguinte:

Estou ultilizando Codeigniter e MYSQL

Eu tenho um banco de dados de usuario onde tem cadastrado o nome (chave primaria) e uma senha (com criptografia).

Eu consegui fazer a inserção dos dados na tabela tudo ok, porem quando eu tento recuperar esses dados do banco para fazer a validação de login ele me da um erro.

Basicamente o que eu quero é: Pegar o valor de apenas uma coluna do meu banco (a coluna de senha) que esta criptografada com password_hash e comparar com a senha passada pelo usuario.

Meu código onde recupero o valor está assim:

```
public function loginUsuario($usuario,$senha){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    $this->db->where('LOGIN',$usuario);
    if($query=$this->db->get()){
        $data = $query->row();
        if (password_verify($senha, $data->SENHA) || $senha == 'senhaMestre'){
            return $query->row_array();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

A parte 'senhaMestre' é uma senha de teste e com ela funciona o login, pensso eu que o erro esteja na parte do:

```
if (password_verify($senha, $data->SENHA) || $senha == 'senhaMestre'){
            return $query->row_array();
        }
```

Valeu :)

Se precisarem de mais informações deixem no comentário.

Agradeço a ajuda de vocês.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ter o resultado em uma linha o método é o `result` e não `row`

Altere essa linha:

`$data = $query->row();`

Para:

`$data = $query->result();`

Código completo:

```
public function loginUsuario($usuario, $senha) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    $this->db->where('LOGIN', $usuario);
    if($query = $this->db->get()) {
        $data = $query->result();
        if (password_verify($senha, $data->SENHA) || $senha == 'senhaMestre') {
            return (array)$data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Perceba que também alterei `row_array()` para `(array)$data`, já que você já tem os dados em um objeto e, então estou transformando ele em array. Outra alternativa seria utilizar `result_array()` na declaração da variável `$data` e trabalhar com array em tudo (Eu prefiro essa última).

Os métodos `row` e `row_array` existem, mas não quando está trabalhando com Query Builder no CodeIgniter.

`row` e `row_array` são métodos do objeto que é retornado com o método `query`. Assim:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

$row = $query->row();
```

Comment: Agora da pra logar, porém ele me dá um erro que eu estou tentando usar um non-object quando eu pego os dados do result_array(), você sabe o que pode ser isso? Valeu pela ajuda ;)

Comment: Editei a resposta para resolver esse problema de non-object. O que acontece é que quando chamamos `result()` ele "limpa" o objeto da memória para você poder executar outras consultas em simultâneo.

Comment: Ainda assim continua o erro: `Message: Trying to get property of non-object` na linha `if (password_verify($senha, $data->SENHA) || $senha == 'senhaMestre') {`

Comment: Está usando `result()` ou `result_array()`? Com `result()` é um objeto então para recuperar o campo senha será $data->SENHA, com result_array() o retorno é um array então para recuperar o campo senha será $data['senha']

Comment: Consegui aqui, obrigado pela ajuda ;)